# PHPmyadmin MYSQL: Viewing rows affected by a transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've started using

```
BEGIN;
<SQL CODE HERE>;
ROLLBACK;
```

To test queries out before commiting the results. It's a very useful to avoid screwing up data, even on local and test databases.

One thing I dislike, however, is that all I get returned is the number of rows affected Like so:

```
BEGIN;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).


UPDATE agenda SET is_ars = 0, question_bank_id = null WHERE session_name LIKE '%closing%';# 1 row affected.


ROLLBACK;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
```

Is there any way to actually SELECT the row that was affected or see it, so that I can ensure my query hit my target, and not something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about doing a `SELECT` after the `UPDATE` with the same `WHERE` condition?

```
BEGIN;

UPDATE `vaccinee records` 
SET `Date of First Dose` = NULL 
WHERE Id = 9;

SELECT * 
FROM `vaccinee records` 
WHERE Id = 9;

ROLLBACK;
```

I'm using phpmyadmin and MariaDB.